# Deserialize json data into list in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am calling an external web service and this is what I get in response after posting to their server:

```js
{
   "status":200,
   "data":{
      "h21":{
         "total_price":{
            "acacia":{
               "available":0,
               "price":null,
               "availability":false
            },
            "maple":{
               "available":7,
               "price":2399.0,
               "availability":true
            }
         }
      },
      "h17":{
         "total_price":{
            "mahogany":{
               "available":1,
               "price":1899.0,
               "availability":true
            },
            "oak":{
               "available":0,
               "price":null,
               "availability":false
            },
            "maple":{
               "available":6,
               "price":1649.0,
               "availability":true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want this response to be converted into a list. I used jsontocsharp online converter to generate class and use code below:

```
var Jsonresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sstageback.Models.Sstage.treeboRoomTypes.RootObject>(JsonReplace);
```

But the thing is mine is a dynamic JSON response which can change over course of time.

Note: The response which I get from the server is hotel and its room availability so while generating classes I can't generate with a single class file since the hotel id's may change also the room types and its availability also changes.

Example: h21 is one hotel id and total_price has its room type details similarly h17 is the next hotel and total_price has its room type details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `TotalPrice` should be a `Dictionary<string, Availability>` or similar. It's not clear what *list* you'd have, but that's naturally a dictionary. That's then nested within a dictionary at the top level.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Response
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Hotel> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel
{
    [JsonProperty("total_price")]
    public Dictionary<string, Room> TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int Available { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public bool Availability { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(text);
        foreach (var pair in response.Data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {pair.Key}");
            foreach (var nestedPair in pair.Value.TotalPrice)
            {
                var room = nestedPair.Value;
                Console.WriteLine($"  {nestedPair.Key}: {room.Available}/{room.Price}/{room.Availability}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key: h21
  acacia: 0//False
  maple: 7/2399.0/True
Key: h17
  mahogany: 1/1899.0/True
  oak: 0//False
  maple: 6/1649.0/True
```

Comment: @Melvin: Um, what about it?

Comment: Sorry i just started typing but an urgent meeting came up.What i came to ask was will i be able to use ng repeat in the frontend using this ??

Comment: @Melvin: I have no idea what "ng repeat" is, I'm afraid. But you can use it just like you'd use any other C# class with the same structure. (If you're talking about AngularJS, then that's Javascript, not C#, so I fail to see how it relates to what you're asking.)

Comment: This response will be used to bind values in frontend using angularjs so if i send response in this format will i be able to repeat over this.

Comment: And btw let me try this and mark this answer as correct so that others may be benefited from your solution,many thanks :)

Comment: I got it with the class you provided now i will make a dictionary(key/value) out of this response and just convert them to whatever i like list/array then bind my data in frontend using angularjs.Thanks Jon Skeet you saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a DTO model that corresponds with the response. The value of a attribute can change, that's no problem, as long as the type stays the same ( an int stays an int and a string stays a string).

Your Object could look like this:

```
public class Room{
    public int Available { get; set;}
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public bool availability { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

You should convert Serialize and Deserialize this. This is only an example, you want your model to be 100% the same as your JSON.

For an easy conversion between Models and DTO, you could use AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/